# Multi-level dropdown buttons in flutter - can we eliminate the if statements?

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, multi-level

I implemented a two levels of dropdown buttons where button# 2 depends on the choice of button #1. first drop down is a list of countries, depending on the user's selection of the country, a list of cities will be available in the second drop down. The main question is about the link between the two drop-downs, I am using a chain of if-statements to tell the code that if I choose country x, display cities of x etc.
In the example code below I am including only 6 countries, so writing if statements is still clean and manageable, but what if the list of countries goes to 150? will I need to write 150 lines of if-statements to link countries to their cities? Is there a smarter way to do this? can I exploit the similarities in the country name and the name of the list containing its cities? e.g. 'USA' and 'cityUSA'

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
String? dropdownValue;
String? dropdownCity;
List<String> selectedCities=[];
String? selectedCountry;
@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final List<String> country = ['USA', 'Egypt', 'Spain', 'Mexico', 'Russia', 'China'];
  final List<String> cityEgypt =['Cairo', 'Alexandria'];
  final List<String> cityUSA = ['Houston', 'Dallas'];
  final List<String> citySpain = ['Madrid', 'Barcelona'];
  final List<String> cityMexico = ['Cancun', 'Mexico City'];
  final List<String> cityRussia=['Moscow', 'Saint Petersburg'];
  final List<String> cityChina = ['Gowanzo', 'Beijing'];
  return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Drop down fun',
      home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      body:Column(
      children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Text('Please choose your location', style:TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25)),
  ),

    Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: DropdownButton<String>(
  value: dropdownValue,
  icon: Icon(Icons.map),
  disabledHint: Text('Choose country first'),

  style:TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15) ,
  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
  setState(() {
  dropdownValue = newValue;
  selectedCountry = dropdownValue;
  dropdownCity = null;
  if(selectedCountry=='Egypt'){selectedCities=cityEgypt;}
  else if(selectedCountry=='USA'){selectedCities=cityUSA;}
  else if(selectedCountry=='Spain'){selectedCities=citySpain;}
  else if(selectedCountry=='Mexico'){selectedCities=cityMexico;}
  else if(selectedCountry=='Russia'){selectedCities=cityRussia;}
  else if(selectedCountry=='China'){selectedCities=cityChina;}
  });
  },
  items: country.map((String item){
  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
  value: item,
  child: Container(
  color: Colors.greenAccent,
    child: Text(item),
  ),
  );
  }
  ).toList()
  ),
  ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
              value: dropdownCity,
              icon: Icon(Icons.map),

              style:TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15) ,
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {

                setState(() {
                  dropdownCity = newValue;});
              },
              items: selectedCities.map((String item){
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: item,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.greenAccent,
                    child: Text(item),
                  ),
                );
              }
              ).toList()
          ),
        ),
  ],
  ),
  ),);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, in any language not specific of dart or being a flutter dropdown button functionality, in such cases you relay over the data *encapsulation* which you will prepare a list of countries objects, each of them contains id, name and a list of their own cities

```
class Country {
   int id;
   String name;
   List<City> cities;
}

class City {
   int id;
   String name;
}
```

so In such case you will have a dropdown of Country not a String

```
DropdownButton<Country>
```

and instead of long "if-else if-else ... else", you will have a direct mapping of cities

```
selectedCities = selectedCountry.cities
```

Comment: Thanks this is easier! I am a beginner and I keep struggling with creating objects and fully utilizing them. What is the reason for using an id number? is it for database book keeping?

Comment: @AbdallahIbrahim usually, you do not need to refer to objects with names, imagine that you will support app localizations (Arabic and English), you will need a lookup key instead of searching with "Egypt" or "مصر", and such data is much better being fetched and linked from the backend (for sure try to avoid hard coded values inside your code).

It would be great also to accept the answer to help other community members.

Try reaching about SOLID Principal for OOP